# Logging and decoding repsonse body from golang net/http library

Tags: go

I'm writing a webhook in Go that parses a JSON payload. I'm attempting to log the raw payload and then decode it immediately after but it fails when I try. If I perform the actions separately, they both work fine independently.

Can someone explain why I can't use `ioutil.ReadAll` and `json.NewDecoder` together?

```
func webhook(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    log.Printf("incoming message - %s", body)

    var p payload
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    err := decoder.Decode(&p)
    if err != nil {
        // Returns EOF
        log.Printf("invalid payload - %s", err)
    }

    defer r.Body.Close()
}
```

Comment: What does "it fails" exactly mean? For json decoding don't use the `r.Body` which you have already read from fully, but the `body`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can someone explain why I can't use `ioutil.ReadAll` and `json.NewDecoder`
>   together?

The request body is an `io.ReadCloser` that reads bytes, more or less, directly from a network connection. The contents of the Body aren't stored in memory by default. That's why after the first time you've read the Body the next time you try to read it you'll get EOF.

So if you need to process the request Body more than once, you **yourself** will have to store the contents into memory, which is what you are already doing with:

```
body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
```

You can then reuse `body` as many times as you like, and since you have the Body contents at your disposal as a `[]byte` value, you can use `json.Unmarshal` instead of `json.NewDecoder(...).Decode`.

---

This is unrelated to your question, but please **do not ignore** the error returned from `ioutil.ReadAll`.

Also you can drop the `defer r.Body.Close()` line, because you do not have to close the request body in your server handlers. (**emphasis mine**)

> For server requests the Request Body is always non-nil but will return
>   EOF immediately when no body is present. **The Server will close the
>   request body. The ServeHTTP Handler does not need to.**

Answer (score 4):

`r.Body` is meant to be read exactly once. 
When you use the `ioutil.ReadAll` function you do read all the data from the body. That's why the decoder which also relies on `r.Body` in fact gets nothing to decode.

Answer (score 4):

Minor additional point about `json.Decoder` and `json.Unmarshal`: at first glance it looks like the only difference between the two is just that the former operates on a stream and the latter on a `[]byte`, but they actually have different semantics.

`json.Unmarshal` will return an error if the data contains more than one json object.  So, for example, it will parse `{}`, but it will not parse `{}{}`.

`json.Decoder` parses one complete object per call to `Decode`, so if you give it `{}{}`, it will parse those two objects and then the third call will return `io.EOF` and it's `More` method will return `false`.

In a normal http body, you probably only want a single object, so you'd want to use `Unmarshal` if you're not worried about loading all the data into memory at once.  You can also use `Decoder` and manually check that there is only one object if you care to do so.

Comment: Nice to know the nuances of `json.Unmarshal` and `json.Decoder`